# Git not using custom origin port, falls back to 22

Tags: git, git-remote

I have remote which has a URL `git@gitea.kong:8088/dusan.work/portfolio.git`, whenever I try to `git push` it returns an error stating:

```
ssh: connect to host gitea.kong port 22: Connection refused
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Further inspecting network traffic with `tcpdump` I figured that it is indeed trying to connect to the port `22`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+ssh+URL+port

Comment: @phd no need for shutting this post down, it still serves as an reminder regarding what you should check in case you get this error, I think its useful for sure, especially for not so versed git users

Comment: There is nothing in the answer that adds anything new to the existing ones. The most upvoted answer at the duplicate question is quite elaborated.

Answer (score -1):

After looking trough many posts I figured that the only issue was missing `ssh://` in front of the remote URL.

Now with `ssh://git@gitea.kong:8088/dusan.work/portfolio.git` its working as intended.